# Get all combinations of replacing a substring in Scala

Tags: scala

Say I have the string `"foo bar foo barfoo foobar"` and I would want all possible combinations of replacing `"foo"` with `"baz"`. How would I do this efficiently in Scala?

Expected output would be:

```
"baz bar foo barfoo foobar"
"foo bar baz barfoo foobar"
"baz bar baz barfoo foobar"
"foo bar foo barbaz foobar"
"baz bar foo barbaz foobar"
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val str = "foo bar foo barfoo foobar"  //beginning string
val toReplace = "foo"

//get all the indices where "foo" is found
val xs = Stream.iterate(str.indexOf(toReplace))(x => str.indexOf(toReplace,x+1))
               .takeWhile(_>=0)

//get all combinations of indices and map each to a patched string
val result: Seq[String] = (1 to xs.length).flatMap(xs.combinations)
                       .map(_.foldLeft(str){_.patch(_, "baz", toReplace.length)})
```

---

```
//build each result string w/o separate intermediate strings
val result: Seq[String] = (1 to xs.length).flatMap(xs.combinations)
                   .map{combo =>
                     val sb = new StringBuilder(str)
                     combo.foreach(x => sb.replace(x, x+toReplace.length, "baz"))
                     sb.toString
                   }
```

Comment: The `foldLeft` creates `n` new strings for every output string (with `n` in `1 to xs.length`). Would there be a way that does not have to create all intermediate strings?

Comment: The problem is that most of the time we need to replace some, but not all, of the "foo" with "baz". Without intermediate `String` values we'd need some form of mutable `String`, like maybe a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Why are you using Java's `StringBuffer` and not Scala's `StringBuilder`?

Comment: You're right, `Builder` is better. I don't use either often and `Buffer` was what came to mind as a mutable collection.